# Auth::user() works but Auth::user()->id breaks within a where query in eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm very confused by this!

In a laravel controller:

```
$user = Auth::user();
return $user;
```

returns the entire user object

```
$user = Auth::user()->id;
return $user;
```

returns the id of $user as expected

however if I put that exact thing into a query such as:

```
$user = Auth::user();
$query = Model::where('user_id', $user->id)->get();

return $query;
```

I get an error that I'm trying to get an 'id' property of a non-object!!!

How can this be possible?

I've also checked 100 times that I'm logged in when testing this.

Editing to add that I've also tried:

```
$query = Model::where('user_id', 1)->get();
```

and that works fine

**edit to show the function:**

```
$user = Auth::id();

        $result = Lesson::where('user_id', $user)
            ->whereNotNull('notes')
            ->get();

return response()->json($result, 200);
```

Expected results: A list of objects with a filled in "notes" column.

Actual results: an empty `[]` and an error saying can't get id of a non-object

Comment: Try $query = Model::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();

Comment: Do you have logged in user at all? You can do a check:
`if (Auth::check()) {
     Auth::id();
  }`

Comment: @EXayer I'm definitely logged in but when I do auth::check() it says i'm not

Comment: @storyks no good same issue

Comment: perhaps besdies the point, but just for future reference: you can also use `Auth::id()` to directly get the id of the logged in user.

Comment: Please show code in file User model

Comment: @storyks do you need to see the linked models? there are a lot. or just the protected vars like fillable etc

Comment: Please show entire function and output vs expected output

Comment: @ege updated w/ code

Comment: `Auth::user()` returns `null` if user isn't logged in. How you checked? How are using your code? It seems you are sending `ajax` request

Comment: Hi @Maribov, just do dd($user); and see what comes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use Auth in Models.
You can set a relation between User and your Model and do query like:

```
Auth::user()->relation()->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

> try this

```
     $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
     $query = Model::where('user_id', $user_id)->get();
     return $query;
```

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs if the `Model` doesn't contain any raw with that user id. Make sure you have the raw in the Model where you are querying to get data by user id.

Answer (score 0):

**You should try this**

```
$user = Auth::user();
$result = Model::where('user_id', $user['id'])->get();
```

- The error occurs because of you passed property of non-object.
- Even after error not solve then restart your `xampp` or `wamp`.
- If possible, upload the screenshot of error.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work if you are authed, it seems your are not based on the error message. Since you return json, i assume this is an api request. Api-routes uses another auth driver as default in Laravel (token vs. session). Either change the driver/guard or move your route(s) from `routes/api.php` to `routes/web.php`.

[See docs for auth](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication)

You can change the driver in `config/auth.php`.